# All undocumented keyboard shortcuts for OS X terminal app?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, terminal

Is there a comprehensive list of the actual keyboard shortcuts available in the terminal app?

Here's an example of an undocumented shortcut: the "select next tab" action in the Window menu is indicated as command + }, but command + shift + right arrow also works, and I actually prefer it.

Note: this is with terminal.app on Snow Leopard. I'm not sure about older versions of OS X, I expect the shortcuts would differ slightly as features have been added to terminal.app over time...

Comment: oop..now that you've documented this shortcut you should probably find another undocumented shortcut to quote :)

Comment: Terminal's Help has a list of shortcut keys. One I use all the time that many people may not be aware of is: Command-Period sends Control-C.

Answer (score 5):

OS-wide shortcuts are listed in Apple's [Mac OS X keyboard shortcuts](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1343) support note.

For all the shortcuts in a particular application, shareware app KeyCue will render them into a nice reference card. KeyBindingsEditor won't render them so nicely but it should let you see them and it's free.

Just web search for those app names.

Answer (score 0):

I think shortcuts are common for most apple products: for Safari you also can use ⌘} and ⌘⇧left, though documentation for Terminal shortcuts doesn't mention second combination, but for Safari does. Also I think that it is better to ask what do you need to do with shortcuts? Using Keyboard prefpane you can change shortcuts and using software like Spark and Quicksilver you can create shortcuts for things that can't be assigned to shortcut as easily.